# Generic value type of Go map

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go, slice

I am working on a web app with Go language. The `respond(writer, html, *params)` function needs a list of parameters which can be used to render an HTML page. I came up with a map as this which works fine:

```
&map[string][]string
```

However, recently I need to squeeze in a value pair in the format of `{string, map[string][]string}` which obviously blew up the compiler. So I am wondering if there is any generic type I can utilize, i.e. `map[string]GenericType`.

Any thoughts is welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps if you express the desired outcome and what `respond` does exactly, we could help better than recommending something as unfriendly as `map[string][]interface{}`, which may be too generic. As your question is currently worded, it's difficult to know what to recommend because it's impossible to know what your goal with `respond` is. You provided too few details about what you want to do for anybody to provide a good recommendation. What does `respond` do? What is `*params` and how does it affect things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So generally you store `[]string` values for `string` keys. Most of the time. And once in a while you'd like to store a `map[string][]string` value for a `string` key.

First, drop the pointer from the map type: maps are already small descriptors, you can pass maps which will pass a copy of the descriptor and not the whole content, and if you add a new key-value pair to the copy, you will see that in the original. Passing a map by value is efficient and has the desired effect / working.

<sup>To be precise: map types are actually pointers to a map descriptor under the hood, but this is an implementation detail, you don't need to know this to use / work with maps. Only thing that matters is you can pass around map values efficiently.</sup>

Keeping only one map and being able to store values of both type `[]string` and `map[string][]string` would require you to change the value type to `interface{}`, but then this would require you to use [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) every time you access an element in the params map, something like:

```
params := map[string]interface{}{}
params["a"] = []string{"b", "c"}

if list, ok := params["a"].([]string); ok {
    fmt.Println(list)
}
```

Of course you could create a new type with `map[string]interface{}` being its underlying type, and add `Get()` and `Set()` methods for the most common value type `[]string`, but instead I recommend a wrapper `struct` for the params, with multiple maps in multiple fields:

```
type Params struct {
    P map[string][]string
    M map[string]map[string][]string
}
```

Your code may use the map whichever has the value type that suits the value to be stored, for example:

```
params2 := Params{map[string][]string{}, map[string]map[string][]string{}}
params2.P["a"] = []string{"b", "c"}

params2.M["B"] = map[string][]string{
    "x": []string{"X", "Y"},
}

fmt.Println(params2.P["a"])
fmt.Println(params2.M["B"])
```

You may also add `Get()` and `Set()` methods to `Params` that get and set elements from the most frequently used `Params.P` map.

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mV96TD8vH3).